# My container moves up into the header when a file is downloaded in Chrome. Not sure how to fix it

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a container and as I've been previewing it in the Chrome browser. I noticed that when I downloaded a file, and the download appeared at the bottom of the browser, the container in my website preview moved up into the header section of the webpage. I'm teaching myself HTML and CSS and I can't figure it out. Here is my CSS code:

```
.container {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;   /*So the border is visible in Mozilla*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /*So the border is visible for browsers using webkit */    
    position: fixed;
    left: 65%;
    width: 24em;
    top: 55%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="social-icons">
         <div class="col_1_of_f span_1_of_f">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="facebookicon.png"/>
            <ul class='facebook'>
                <i class="fb"> </i>
                <li>Connect with Facebook</li>
                <div class='clear'> </div>
            </ul>
          </a>
         </div> 
         <div class="col_1_of_f span_1_of_f">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="twitter-logo.png"/>
            <ul class='twitter'>
                <i class="tw"> </i>
                <li>Connect with Twitter</li>
                <div class='clear'> </div>
            </ul>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>  
      </div>

    <!--FIELD INFORMATION-->    
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" class="input" required pattern=.*\S.* />
            <label for="firstname" class="label">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" id="lastname" class="input" required pattern=.*\S.* />
            <label for="lastname" class="label">Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" id="email" class="input" required pattern=.*\S.* />
            <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="password" id="password" class="input" required pattern=.*\S.* />
            <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="password" id="password2" class="input" required pattern=.*\S.* />
            <label for="password2" class="label">Password (again)</label>
        </div>
        <h6>By creating an account, you agree to our <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>.</h6>
        <div class="profile__footer">
          <button class="btn">Sign-Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The position is `fixed` and not `float`. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: we need more info to reproduce the problem, please post the relevant html and css

Comment: @cocoa Just added the HTML code

Comment: Does the same happen when you reduce the height of the window?

Comment: @Shomz Yes, when I adjust the size of the webpage the container doesn't become smaller or larger, it remains the same size and just floats on the page. It doesn't stay in a fixed position.

Comment: Understood, the percentages are the same, but their actual values change because the window size changes (for example: 50% of 200px and 50% of 180px are not the same)... I explained it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, seriously! I'll try it out and mark your answer. Thanks! @Shomz

Comment: You're welcome, @Kayla! Just calculate those vertical offsets in pixels, and you'll be good to go. Or, if you can, completely drop the fixed positioning and simply lay block elements one on top of another, as they work by default.

Comment: No problem. Hmmm, it's because of the fixed position and top offset. It's used to achieve that effect. Don't use it if you want elements to behave normally (you'd probably have to remove the transform rule as well.

Comment: Thanks again! I fixed it by removing the fixed position and replaced it with `float: right;` I adjusted the margins as needed. You're an awesome guy! Thanks @Shomz

Comment: Awesome! Haha, thank you, @Kayla, I'm glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the following two rules for your container:

```
top: 55%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

It's a vertical positioning "hack" that relies on the window height (unless you have a relatively positioned parent, those rules are in relation to the window). What happens when you download a file is that you lose a little piece of the window height, because of that little Chrome's download box.

Not sure how exactly it looks like, but the way to fix it is to use pixels for both `top` and the vertical component of `transform: translate` rules.

Generally, you should avoid using percentages for fixed elements, not only because of Chrome's download box, but because different users will have different website experiences unless they all have the identical window height (which you can **never** count on).